# How to detect if a revision was made by woocommerce or wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce-offtopic

As WordPress since version 4.6.1 or so ignores `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);` definition (at least in my WP instance), it tries to make as much revisions as possible.

Even if a post or a WooCommerce product was opened for just `CTRL+A -> CTRL+C` and then closed without editing, in most cases I'll get a nice but totally unneeded revision entry in the database for that particular post.

As I don't think it is a good idea to forcibly delete anything directly in mySQL database I'd better turn revisions into post drafts or product drafts using the following not so difficult SQL query:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_date` = '2222-12-31 00:00:00' WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'revision';
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status` = 'draft' WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'revision';
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_type` = 'post' WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'revision';
```

But unfortunately both post revisions or product revisions look absolutely the same in `wp_posts` table comparing their `post_status` and `post_type` entries, so the product revisions turn into post drafts after applying the above query.

So my question is how could I detect WooCommerce product revisions and turn them into product drafts before doing the same for post revisions?

Comment: Were you able to test this solution?

Comment: Not yet. WooCommerce haven't added any revision by itself for the moment. I'll try it immediately when I have both WP and WC revisions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce uses the post_type `product` for products, so it should be easy enough to search for those instead of posts.

Just look out for the proper `post_type`.

You could filter the revisions using a self-joined select like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts` p1
LEFT JOIN `wp_posts` p2 ON (p2.post_parent = p1.ID and p1.post_type = 'products')
WHERE p1.`post_type` = "revision"
LIMIT 50
```

Still, I wouldn't convert my revisions into posts nor anything like that. You'll end up with TONS of garbage posts laying around.

Comment: ...But unfortunately both post revisions or product revisions look absolutely the same in `wp_posts` table comparing their `post_status` and `post_type` entries...